# How can I upload more than 10 images in a category map?

Tags: cartography, carto, image

I did a category map with 30 different categories. For each, I would like to upload an image but the "wizards" permits me to upload only ten images and then one image for "others".

Is it possible to upload more?

Comment: I forgot to say that it is on cartodb, sorry.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way around this on CartoDB, but wanted to mention that 30 categories is a rather high number to try depicting on a map. Is there anyway you could combine, group, or otherwise shave off some of those?

Answer (score 1):

By default CartoDB creates 10 categories, but you can create more of them in your CartoCSS code.

You'll have something like:

```
#tablename[column = 'Text']{
marker-fill: #ccc;
}
```

You just need to add as many blocks with that syntax as you need, and add inside of them the CartoCSS options that you want per each category. Remember to update the Legends too!